# Display trace for non-debug AS3 application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, logging, trace

A client is running into some problems with an application, and cannot install the debug flash player, meaning debugging is very hard.

Does anyone know of a way to display the system's trace messages in a textfield on the stage for example? This way I could find the error by having it trace to their screen.

I suppose a workaround would be to try/catch all over the application but that is not ideal and very cumbersome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I have recently started to do is use an ExternalInterface call to debug Flash, using the Firebug console, or whatever console your browser supports.

We use this snippet of Javascript from Html5Boilerplate:

```
window.log = function(){
  log.history = log.history || [];
  log.history.push(arguments);
  arguments.callee = arguments.callee.caller;  
  if(this.console) console.log( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );
};
(function(b){function c(){}for(var d="assert,count,debug,dir,dirxml,error,exception,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,info,log,markTimeline,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,trace,warn".split(","),a;a=d.pop();)b[a]=b[a]||c})(window.console=window.console||{});
```

And then use

```
ExternalInterface.call('window.log','Debug text goes here');
```

Answer (score 0):

What I used to do in cases like that is inserting a hidden log panel into application. This panel should open after some secret key sequence is pressed. When you need some information, you uncover the sequence to a client and ask to copy and send you everything he sees in log textfield. Until then no one even knows it's there. This is applicable to whatever app you may develop, not only to web apps. Well, if you are developing a web app, you way even automate that by sending the report to you through some cgi script along with a screenshot. You just ask your client to press something specific, and then you check your mail.

You also may want to use UncaughtErrorEvents: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvents.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2

Below is some simple code I use for locking debug output.

```
protected const inputHistory : Array = [];
private var lockPhrase : String;
private var isUnlocked : Boolean;

private function onKeyUp(event : KeyboardEvent) : void
{
    isUnlocked = checkLock();
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        if (event.shiftKey) {
            if (isUnlocked) {
                // log panel opens by Shift + Space shortcut
                // only if it was previously unlocked
                toggle(true);
            }
        }
    }
    if (lockPhrase && lockPhrase.length) {
        inputHistory.push(event.charCode);
        while (inputHistory.length > lockPhrase.length) {
            inputHistory.shift();
        }
    }
}

private function checkLock() : Boolean
{
    if (isUnlocked || lockPhrase == null || lockPhrase.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (inputHistory.length != lockPhrase.length) {
        return false;
    }
    var match:uint = 0;
    for (var i : uint = 0; i < lockPhrase.length; i+=1) {
        if (lockPhrase.charCodeAt(i) == inputHistory[i]) {
            match += 1;
        }
    }
    return (match == lockPhrase.length);
}
```